# Using Robocopy with Powershell 5

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I upgraded my development machine to Powershell 5 and now code that works in PS2 does not in PS5.

My code uses Robocopy to copy files from a svn checkout directory to a working directory. It is also used to clean the working directory.

The original code looks like this:

```
    $what = @("""/copy:DAT""","""/E""","/XD .svn","/XD Debug","/XF .pdb")
    $options = @("""/R:4""","""/W:5""","""/TS""","""/NS""","""/Tee""","""/NP""")
    if ($file) {
        $cmdArgs = @("""$src""", """$dest""", """$file""", $what, $options)
    }else
    {
        $cmdArgs = @("""$src""", """$dest""", $what, $options)
    }
    robocopy $cmdArgs
```

When the command runs using powershell 5 I get

> ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "/copy:DAT /E /XD .svn /XD Debug /XF
>   .pdb"

I see what is occuring, it is treating the parameter as one single command rather than separate parameters.
I have tried single double quotes, I have tried single quotes, but I still get the same result.

If I hard code the options to the execute line,

> robocopy $cmdArgs /COPY:DAT /E /XD .svn /XD Debug /XF .pdb /R:4 /W:5
>   /TS /NS /Tee /NP

then the command will work, so I have a workaround for now, but still would rather have the original parameterized structure.

What do I need to do to get this working for PS5? Thank you.

EDIT: With Windows 10 and PS5, I am getting the following error:
ERROR: Invalid Parameter #5 : "/XD .svn"

```
$what = @("""/PURGE""","""/E""","/XD .svn","/XD Debug","/XF .pdb")
$options = @("""/R:4""","""/W:5""","""/TS""","""/NS""","""/Tee""","""/NP""")
$cmdArgs = @("""$srcBase""","""$targetPath"""; $what)
```

For the '/XD .svn' I have tried enclosing it with triple quotes, single quotes, escaped quotes, etc. However, no success.

Comment: `, $what, $options` -> `; $what; $options`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this fails with the same issue. Can someone do me a favor and try the same scenario with PowerShell 5? I realize this is a jagged array, and I suspect that is where PowerShell is getting confused. However, I need a way to execute robocopy in powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! What a pain, but I have a solution. 
I had to use the string split method and split on spaces. I had to ditch the array and create a single string.

```
$cmdArgs = @("""$srcBase""", """$targetPath""") #still required for quoted paths
$what = "/PURGE /E /XD .svn /XD DEBUG /XF .pdb"
$options = "/R:4 /W:5 /TS /NS /Tee /NP"
robocopy $cmdArgs $what.split(' ') $options.split(' ')
```

Something between PS 2.0 and later version changed that broke my code, but this seems to fix it. Hopefully this helps save others from days of pain. :)

EDIT: After reflecting on this I suppose that this is an issue between PS and Robocopy where parameters with values do not evaluate properly. What shames me is that it took so many tries for me to try a simple string as the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Too many mind boggling quotes! You really don't need them at all except for your source path and your destination path. Best way I found is to create a formatted string expression and then execute it.

```
$what = "/copy:DAT /E /XD .svn /XD Debug /XF .pdb"
$options = "/R:4 /W:5 /TS /NS /Tee /NP"
$source = "C:\DataSource"
$destination = "D:\DataDestination"

$expression = [string]::Format('ROBOCOPY "{0}" "{1}" {2} {3}', $source,$Destination,$what,$options)
$rc = Invoke-Expression $expression
$rc = $LASTEXITCODE;
    Switch ($rc)
{
    0 {$msg = 'No files were copied. No failure was encountered. No files were mismatched.'}
    1 {$msg = 'All files were copied successfully.'} 
    2 {$msg = 'There are some additional files in the destination directory that are not present in the source directory. No files were copied.'}
    3 {$msg = 'Some files were copied. Additional files were present. No failure was encountered.'}
    5 {$msg = 'Some files were copied. Some files were mismatched. No failure was encountered.'}
    6 {$msg = 'Additional files and mismatched files exist. No files were copied and no failures were encountered. This means that the files already exist in the destination directory.'}
    7 {$msg = 'Files were copied, a file mismatch was present, and additional files were present.'}
    8 {$msg = 'Several files did not copy.'}
    default {$msg = 'Robocopy failed with an error'}
}
$msg
If($rc -ge 8) {Throw}
```

Comment: After hours of googling, this answer (in 2021) is the ONLY way I can get Powershell to execute Robocopy with a dynamic array of arguments *that includes complex /XF and /XD lists*.  The many arguments are just put together in a flat string variable, not splatted, no array, just parsed together using Format

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing a jagged array. You can verify this by looking at the results of $cmdargs after running the code you included

```
""
""
"/copy:DAT"
"/E"
/XD .svn
/XD Debug
/XF .pdb
"/R:4"
"/W:5"
"/TS"
"/NS"
"/Tee"
"/NP"
```

This looks right, but if you just access the third element $cmdArgs[2] you can see that it encompasses the entire contents of the $what array

```
"/copy:DAT"
"/E"
/XD .svn
/XD Debug
/XF .pdb
```

As a quick and dirty workaround, try the following:

```
    $what = @("""/copy:DAT""","""/E""","/XD .svn","/XD Debug","/XF .pdb")
    $options = @("""/R:4""","""/W:5""","""/TS""","""/NS""","""/Tee""","""/NP""")
    if ($file) {
        $cmdArgs = @("""$src""", """$dest""", """$file""")
        $cmdArgs += $what
        $cmdArgs += $options
    }else
    {
        $cmdArgs = @("""$src""", """$dest""")
        $cmdArgs += $what
        $cmdArgs += $options
    }
    robocopy $cmdArgs
```

EDIT:
Slight edits above, and
[More on Jagged vs Multidimensional vs standard arrays here](http://pwrshell.net/back-to-basics-arrays/). Look toward the bottom. Essentially, the way you are building your array is interpreted as @(0,1,(0,1,2,3,4),(0,1,2,3,4,5))

Comment: I am sorry for the response delay, it was a tyranny of the urgent situation. :) I am on a Windows 10 x86 system, and of course it uses PowerShell 5 and I am still encountering the same problems. I cannot properly construct a command line that parses correctly. When I go back to PowerShell 2.0 machine the command line parses perfectly. I tried the suggestion above but get the same results.